# onmousewheel event not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Styling/Headers Lists Blockquotes Code HTML advanced help »

```
<script>
 function event_branding() {
         document.getElementById("branding_fade").style.bottom = "0%";
         document.getElementById("branding_fade").style.opacity = "1";
         document.getElementById("branding_fade").style.transition = "all 2s";
         setTimeout(function () { $(".event_branding").css("visibility", "visible")},100); 
 }
</script>
```

Comment: this is the calling function

Comment: function event_branding() {
    document.getElementById("branding_fade").style.bottom = "0%";
    document.getElementById("branding_fade").style.opacity = "1";
    document.getElementById("branding_fade").style.transition = "all 2s";
    setTimeout(function () { $(".event_branding").css("visibility", "visible") }, 100);
   
}

Comment: [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mousewheel)

Comment: can you add the code to the question rather than as a comment

Comment: there's absolutely no reference to mousewheel in your code!?!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Onmousewheel event and Mozilla Firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26329617/onmousewheel-event-and-mozilla-firefox)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<div class="col-xs-7" style="padding-right:3px;">
    <img id="train_1_img" class="imageshow_temp" src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff"/>
</div>
```

use this script

```
var image = document.getElementById("train_1_img");
  if (image.addEventListener) {
   // IE9, Chrome, Safari, Opera
    image.addEventListener("mousewheel", MouseWheelEvent);
   // Firefox
    image.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", MouseWheelEvent);
}

function MouseWheelEvent(e) {
console.log('event', e)
// your statement here...
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fahadsaeed/f8ky3xkq/

Answer (score 0):

This will work.

```
window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', mouseWheelEvent);
```

Here is a Jquery example.

http://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/vLerPM

Now, why this is not working for everyone or all browsers is because this is not a standard feature.

Also, MDN says:

On Gecko 17 (Firefox 17) or later, you need to call preventDefault() of wheel events which must be fired for every native event.

On Gecko 16 or earlier, you need to call preventDefault() of MozMousePixelScroll event which must be fired for every native event.

To summarize, browser support is very bad, do not use this for production sites.

Comment: The least you could do is format correctly. Please explain why it works and not just post code

Comment: i'm using this code to call the function                                                                                                                                                             document.getElementById("event_branding1").addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', event_branding());          But not working in Firefox

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not very clear. Anyways I will put my example here hope it helps

```
document.getElementById("myDIV").addEventListener("wheel", foo);
function foo() {
    console.log("Wheel scrolled")
}
```

Try it out in [JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/84qeesk0/1/)

I tested and it works in Firefox and Chrome as well

A more detailed work on browser compatibility is explained [HERE](http://var%20mousewheelevt=(/Firefox/i.test(navigator.userAgent))?%20%22DOMMouseScroll%22%20:%20%22mousewheel%22%20//FF%20doesn't%20recognize%20mousewheel%20as%20of%20FF3.x%20%20%20if%20(document.attachEvent)%20//if%20IE%20(and%20Opera%20depending%20on%20user%20setting)%20%20%20%20%20document.attachEvent(%22on%22%20mousewheelevt,%20function(e)%7Balert('Mouse%20wheel%20movement%20detected!')%7D)%20else%20if%20(document.addEventListener)%20//WC3%20browsers%20%20%20%20%20document.addEventListener(mousewheelevt,%20function(e)%7Balert('Mouse%20wheel%20movement%20detected!')%7D,%20false))